# Devise: NameError (undefined local variable or method `user_id=') in controller when using `current_user`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, has-many, belongs-to

I'm using Devise in my Rails app. A `Project` belongs to a (devise) `User`. (Relevant models are below.)

When the `create` action is called in `ProjectsController`, however, the following error is shown in the server logs:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `user_id=' for #<Project:0x007f4c1a0aa3a8>):
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:20:in `create'
```

Any ideas?

**Project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :timestamps 
end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :projects 
end
```

**projects_controller.rb (relevant parts)**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user! 

def create
    @project = current_user.projects.new(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'

  devise_for :users

  resources :projects do
    resources :timestamps
  end 

end
```

It's the `@project = current_user` line that's causing the problem. Looks like it isn't recognising the method, which is weird.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Do you have `user_id` column in `projects` table?

Comment: Paste your schema.rb file.

Comment: Found the problem! In my over-enthusiasm I forgot to add a foreign key to the `projects` table. I'll add my correction as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else makes the same mistake and doesn't think to check their db schema, here's what was causing the problem.

I'd forgotten to add a foreign key (`user_id`) to the `projects` table, even though I'd added the `belongs_to` association in the model.

To fix the problem, I ran the following migration:

```
class AddUserToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference(:projects, :user, foreign_key: true, index: true)
  end
end
```

and then of course ran `rake db:migrate`